# Gala Greeters and Replacement Effect

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have both [Gala Greeters](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gala%20Greeters) and [Jinnie Fay, Jetmir's Second](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jinnie%20Fay%2C%20Jetmir%27s%20Second) on the battlefield.

A creature comes into play that triggers Gala Greeters's Alliance ability, which should create a tapped Treasure token BUT a replacement effect from Jinnie Fay comes into play and I decided to create a 2/2 Cat creature token with haste. Will the token enter the battlefield tapped or untapped?

Comment: FYI: We have functioning `[mtg:card name]` syntax you can use for card references instead of fetching a gatherer link. It won't show up in the post preview, but it'll work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The token will enter the battlefield tapped.**

The [Streets of New Capenna release notes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/streets-new-capenna-release-notes-2022-04-20) contain the following ruling for Jinnie Fay (emphasis mine):

> The tokens' characteristics are entirely replaced by either 2/2 green Cat creature token with haste or 3/1 green Dog creature token with vigilance. They don't have any other abilities the tokens would have been created with. **Anything else specified in the effect creating the tokens (such as *tapped*, attacking, "That token gains haste," or "Exile that token at end of combat") still applies.**